# Question regarding Hankel functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bessel-functions

I'm studying Hankel functions and I specifically need to calculate the $L^2$ norm of the Hankel function of the first kind (or approximate it), but I'm having real trouble with doing so. I've looked around all over the internet as well as all kinds of books, but I can not find anything to help me. So I thought I'd ask if anyone happens to know any methods of doing that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you write out the exact integral you want to calculate in MathJax?

Comment: @Ian I don't what MathJax is, but I can show the integral I'm trying to compute:

Comment: $$\left(\int_{L}|\frac{i}{4}H_{0}^{(1)}(k|x-y|)|^2\ dy\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: My problem simply lies with the Hankel function, since it's a very complicated function. I've tried to look at upper bounds for the Hankel function, but I can not find any... I do know that the norm of the Hankel function exists and is finite, but sadly I don't know much else.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with your notation about the limits of integration and where $x$ is? I mainly ask because when I look up portions of the answer to your question, I find things diverge.

Comment: Well, $L$ is just a bounded domain I'm integrating over. The domain can vary, but my main problem is simply integrating the Hankel function. It's impossible for me to express an integral with a Hankel function in it. I've looked up upper bounds for the Hankel but there's nothing to find.

Comment: So after changing variables, you're trying to integrate $|H_0^{(1)}(|x|)|^2$ over a completely arbitrary bounded interval, not necessarily even containing $0$? I suppose even if $0$ is excluded you can always write it in terms of a difference of two integrals with $0$ included...

Comment: Is your problem fixed or do you need a result that is a function of $L$ and $k$? If it is fixed then you should be able to compute the result quickly using software...

Comment: I'm trying with various domains and values of $k$, but it's just the given result I'm interested in. I can not seem to get any software to compute it for me.

Comment: For fixed $L,k,x$ you should have no problem evaluating it numerically using standard software like Matlab. I don't mean symbolic, I mean just getting a number.

Comment: I haven't used Matlab to compute it, so perhaps it should be possible with that. Thanks for the help, it's highly appreciated!